# Is there a way to detect when a key is pressed only once? (not held down)

Tags: c++

I have been looking for ways to detect when a key has been pressed but only once, but the only things I can find are GetAsyncKeyState and GetKeyState. I am making a rhythm game for fun and I use a while(true) statement to get everything done. Is there anyway to detect when a key is pressed once? (I'm also using GLFW if that helps)

Comment: Since you mentioned `GetAsyncKeyState` are you writing an windows program?

Comment: If you were making a GUI app, you could handle `WM_KEY(DOWN|UP)` messages, which carry a repeat count you can look at. But in a console app, you don't get that info from `Get(Async)KeyState()`. But you can from `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD)`. Otherwise, just create a state machine, and keep it updated whenever `Get(Async)KeyState()` reports a different state then what is in your state machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the state of the previous key presses, if it was not pressed in the last frame and is now, that would mean that the key is held down.

Here's an example with the LMB:

```cpp
bool previousMouseState = false;
if (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0) {
  if (!prevMouseState) {
    previousMouseState = true;
    //Mouse clicked.
  }
} else previousMouseState = false;
```